# Handling Duplicated Sub-Profiles within spring.profiles.group

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm in the process of migrating from Spring Boot 2.3 to 2.7. I have a question about Spring profile configuration.

When sub-profiles are duplicated between groups declared in spring.profiles.group, could you please explain how the profiles are applied? In other words, what is the priority order between these profiles?

Here is an example of an application.yml for reference.

```yaml
# application.yml
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      dev: common
      cloud: common, springcloud, metrics, cloudlogging
      prod: common, prod

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: common
...

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: cloud
...

---
```

I will apply the 'cloud' and 'prod' profiles to the application.
In what order are the common, springcloud, metrics, cloud, and logging profiles applied?